# How to run a python script from web into a terminal

Tags: python, html, networking, terminal

I have few python scripts which scans the network, e.g. ping, tracert and I am making a web application to do this, now I was wondering is there a way that I can run the python script on the cmd/terminal from a web application.

Comment: What are you using to make your web application? You can use Django and Flask and then put your script inside views.

Comment: thanks paolo i am planning to use Django

Comment: if that's the case then you just have to put your scripts inside your Django App's view.

Answer (score 0):

To run Python scripts with the python command, you need to open a command-line and type in the word python, or python3 if you have both versions, followed by the path to your script, just like this:

```
$ python3 hello.py
Hello World!
```

If everything works okay, after you press Enter, you’ll see the phrase Hello World! on your screen. That’s it! You’ve just run your first Python script!

If this doesn’t work right, maybe you’ll need to check your system PATH, your Python installation, the way you created the hello.py script, the place where you saved it, and so on.

This is the most basic and practical way to run Python scripts

Comment: thanks for you reply but that wasn't the question actually i have few networking scripts i am making a web application for e.g. i will have a button that says ping so once the user clicks on it i want it to perform a ping from the terminal